django channels took to long to shut down and was killed error in backend
I used django channels in this project and created a consumer in the following code:
class WSConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

def connect(self):
    self.room_name = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["room_name"]
    self.stid=self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["stid"]
    self.types=self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["types"]

    self.room_group_name = f"station_{self.room_name}"

    if (self.types=="student"):
        try:
            workclass=WorkClass.objects.get(workclass_id=self.room_name)
            st=Station.objects.get(id=self.stid)
            if st in workclass.stations.all():
                st.state=True
                st.save()
                async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
                        self.room_group_name, self.channel_name
                )
                self.accept()
            else:
                self.disconnect(10)
        except WorkClass.DoesNotExist:
            self.disconnect(10)       
    elif(self.types=="teacher"):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name, self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()  
                   
        except WorkClass.DoesNotExist:
            raise StopConsumer()
        
    else:
        raise StopConsumer()
    

def disconnect(self, close_code):
  
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
        self.room_group_name, self.channel_name
    )
    if(self.types=="student"):
        st=Station.objects.get(id=self.stid)
        st.state=False
        st.save()
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {"type":"list_stations","message":self.room_name,"roles":"stations"}
        )


async def websocket_disconnect(self, message):
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {"type":"list_stations","message":self.room_name,"role":"stations"}
    )
    await super().websocket_disconnect(message)

def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json["message"]
    role=text_data_json['roles']
    types=text_data_json['type']
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
        self.room_group_name,
        {"type":types,"message":message,"role":role}
    )
                  


# Receive message from room group
#list of method...

in settings i used this configuration:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'daphne',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

 #apps
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = "backend.asgi.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
"default": {
    "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
    "CONFIG": {
        "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
    },
},
}

The problem is that after some time in the server terminal it shows the error "took to long to shut down and was killed", this time is variable.
In the meantime, I run it on the front-end by accessing through the IP address on another computer
No matter how much I googled and tried every solution, it didn't work.

Looking at your code here, you have a WebsocketConsumer, one that is running synchronously that is, trying to use this disconnect function that calls async_to_sync.
That function is used when we want to have an Asynchronous program start a synchronous process. However, our program is not Asynchronous.
Instead of a WebsocketConsumer object here, we need a AsyncWebsocketConsumer.
Please let me know of this solves your issue!
